# RichTextBox UseCompatibleTextRendering?

Tags: c#, text, rendering, aero

is there a way to activate CompatibleTextRendering in a standard RichTextBox?
I've got my forms in the aero-design (ExtendDWMFrameworkIntoClientArea) and it's really annoying having everything text-wise in the colour of the window. I've got the option for labels and buttons, but not for TextBoxes and RichTextBoxes.

Thanks in advance.